# Speech Recognition on Visual Basic 6

Tags: vb6

There is a way to integrate Speech Recognition within Visual Basic 6 projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some useful resources about that:

**[Youtube Video on Speech Recognition in VB6](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wAPfs0aT0vU)**
**[VB and Voice Recognition](http://www.codeguru.com/vb/gen/vb_misc/plugins/article.php/c11019)**
**[VB6 Speech Recognition](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/84973-visual-basic-60-speech-recognition/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can add voice and text to speech to your program using the Microsoft Speech SDK (software developer kit).You can download version 4.0a from here:

http://www.martin2k.co.uk/vb6/tips/vb_10.php

Once you have downloaded the SDK, you will need to do 'training' so that the accuracy of the voice recognition is increased.

source: http://www.martin2k.co.uk/vb6/tips/vb_10.php